# Issue with rotating a bitmap on custom view based on touch position on the screen on Android

Tags: android, matrix, android-custom-view, ontouchlistener, rotatetransform

I am having problems implementing this pattern. I have an custom view which has an image drawn on it. The user can take a corner of the image and drag it around, which results in rotation of the image.

[image]

In order to achieve this result I did the following:
The bitmap is stored in an object which also has angle, x, y, centerX and centerY properties.

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                int currentX = (int) event.getX();
                int currentY = (int) event.getY();

               double rotationAngleRadians = Math.atan2(currentX - image.getCenterX(), image.getCenterY() - currentY);
               int rotationAngleDegrees = (int) Math.toDegrees(rotationAngleRadians);
               rotateMatrix.setRotate(rotationAngleDegrees , image.getCenterX(), image.getCenterX());
         .....
}
```

and then in onDraw I use the matrix to rotate the canvas

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
    canvas.setMatrix(rotateMatrix);

   canvas.drawBitmap(image.getBitmap, image.getX(), image.getY(), imagePaint);
   canvas.restore();
}
```

The problem with this approach is the following: when The user starts to drag the button, the whole image "jumps up" 25 pixels and after that it starts to rotate. How can I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that when you give the canvas your matrix, the canvas is disregarding a previous translation which was defined in its previous matrix.

A cleaner approach would be to just use the `canvas.rotate(...)` method, instead of using matrixes. If you must use the matrix class, then make sure you're basing it on the original `canvas.getMatrix()`

Comment: I need to use matrixes since each image will have its own rotation angle. I suppose this could be done with simple canvas.rotate, however I also need to translate the button x,y so I can detect future presses, and for this I need the Matrix object. Not to mention that in the end it will have multiple images, each with its own matrix.

Comment: you can still use canvas.rotate & canvas.translate methods in between canvas.save & canvas.restore calls for each image. It will make your code much more comfortable to use. Still, if you insist on using matrixes, then you need to make sure you're taking into account the existing matrix of the canvas before you give it a new one.

Comment: Let me start by giving you a `GIGANTIC` thank you for opening my eyes. I lived under the impression that the `onDraw` canvas could not `mapPoints`. So, after dropping the individual `Matrix` approach and using the view's `canvas` to rotate and `mapPoints` everything works as expected, not to mention that this fixed one of my other questions opened. Thank you for saving me from another 2-3 days of research and waste of time.

Comment: Added a small +50 bounty to reward your answer. You saved me from a lot of stress.

Comment: im very grateful. once again, glad I could help :)